# tcpdump does not display packets seen by Wireshark

Tags: linux, networking, tcpdump

The host (seen below) receives DNS requests from another host on the same network. It has port UDP/53 closed, still the packets are displayed by Wireshark.

Indeed, the are requests sent to 192.168.16.2 on port UDP/53, so the expression should be right:

```
tcpdump -v -s0 udp and dst port 53 and dst 192.168.16.2
```

If I do:

```
tcpdump -v -s0 udp
```

the DNS requests aren't displayed either.

Why doesn't tcpdump display the DNS requests, and how can I make it display them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your machine has several network interfaces, then you also need to set the interface to listen on using the `-i` option.

Your expression would then read:

```
tcpdump -v -s0 -i eth1 udp and dst port 53 and dst 192.168.16.2
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. tcpdump was listening on the Internet-facing interface, while it should listen on a virtual interface...

Comment: No.  The problem is that you told Wireshark to listen on "eth1" and didn't tell TCPDump where to listen, so it listened on the default of "eth0"